# Find row index for array index in jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables to display a paginated table. I now want to jump to the page that contains a certain row (with the current filter/sort settings). If I know the index of the row I can easily do this with something like `tbl.fnPageChange( Math.floor(rowi / tbl.fnSettings()._iDisplayLength) );`.

However, I only know the index of the *data object* in the data array (as returned by `tbl.fnGetData()`).

Is there a simple way to get the row index based on this data index? So pretty much the opposite of `fnGetPosition()`?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index() doesn't do what you're looking for?

Comment: @Nils, did you figure this out?

Comment: @Margo, Yeah, just posted an answer with my 'solution'. It's pretty hacky though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I hacked something together based on looping through the aiDisplay array:

```
function find_display_index(dataTable, data_index) {
    var oSettings = dataTable.fnSettings();
    var row_index = -1;
    for(var j = 0; j < oSettings.aiDisplay.length; j++) {
        if(oSettings.aiDisplay[j] == data_index) {
            row_index = j;
            break;
        }
    }
    return row_index;
}
```

Not sure if this is the best (or even totally correct) way, but it seems to work!